# Send Email from localhost to gmail address using php mailer

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am sending email from localhost via gmail using PHP mailer this is my code but the main problem is that when i run the script the doesnot show me any error and i am not receiving any email in gmail id

```
include("email/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body = "This is just a Test Email";

$mail->IsSMTP();

// enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  

// sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

// set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Port = 465;                   

// GMAIL username
$mail->Username = "Mygmail id";

// GMAIL password
$mail->Password   = "password";        
$mail->From       = "Mygmail id";
$mail->FromName   = "My Name";

$mail->Subject    = "Testing Message";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible    
email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress("Receiver Gmail Id");

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

And Please dont make my question as duplicate beacause i tried all other answers but not find any solution

Comment: It is a duplicate, this is covered extensively [in the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), you're using an old version of PHPMailer and have failed to use [the gmail example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) with it. Generally it doesn't look like you're trying very hard.

Answer (score 2):

> server : smtp.gmail.com
>
> port : 587
>
> secure tls

try change that ....
i have heard some years ago about this problem, after some hours that i spent, i found that i mus change the port

Comment: Means i have to include that code in my file $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; and change the port to 587 and $mail->Server = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Comment: This is correct, but it only says what the PHPMailer docs say too, so it's not as if this is news!

Comment: as far as i know, yess you shoud add/change it